# Where has my app gone - Microsoft Azure App Services

Tags: azure

Started using the new Azure portal but some of our test apps seem to have disappeared under App Services. In the old portal these lived a level below the main app (deployment slots) and needed a triangle icon to be pressed to view them. Searching under "App services" does not reveal them.

The sites in question still work fine, so they must be there somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are deployment slots.
Look for the deployment slots in the All Settings blade of the main Web App.